# Jupyter Lab will not launch from macOS terminal due to import error

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-lab

I am trying to open jupyter lab on my macOS 12.5 and using terminal shell bash, but I receive the following error:

```
from rpds import HashTrieMap, HashTrieSet, List
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'HashTrieMap' from 'rpds' (unknown location)

I have python 3.11 installed and also tried installing and uninstalling both rpds and rpds-py, but still having the same issue. Does anyone have any idea what could be wrong?

I really appreciate any help!

Comment: You seem to be leaving out some steps of what you are doing and trying to do and seeing? What are you typing on your command line to lead to that? Was JupyterLab already working at some point? How did you install JupyterLab? What are the actual error messages shown?